# Java: JPanel border rotates but the background does not

Tags: java, rotation, jpanel

Have a strange problem with rotating a JPanel.

```
JPanel pnlDummy = new javax.swing.JPanel()
    {
        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
        {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2d.rotate(17 * (Math.PI/180));
        };
    };
    pnlDummy.setBackground(Color.red);
    pnlDummy.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new java.awt.Color(0, 153, 0), 4));
    pnlDummy.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(200,100));
    pnlDummy.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,100));
    pnlDummy.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(200,100));

    pnlParent.add(pnlDummy);
```

I have this:

[image]

Instead, I would like to have the red background rotated just as the border did. What am I missing? Thank you!

Comment: The `paintComponent(g)` you override controls painting inside the `JPanel`. The `JPanel`'s layout does not change, and the background fills it. If you want to change the way the background is painted, paint it in the overridden `paintComponent(g)`.  If you want to change the way the `JPanel` is painted within its parent, you need to override the parent's `paintComponent(g)`

Comment: Thank you, cOder. The problem is clear now. It is not clear though how I could change the JPanel's layout overriding the `paintComponent(g)` method of the parent panel. Thanks!

Comment: See answer for some more info

Comment: cOder. Thank you for your time. Unfortunately, whereas you pointed to the problem, there was no clear solution proposed. Overriding `paintComponent(g)` does not solve the problem. I upvoted your response to recognize that you spent your time. But I can't mark it as the one that solved the problem. Thank you, anyways.

Answer (score 1):

The `paintComponent(g)` you override controls painting inside the JPanel.
The `JPanel`'s layout does not change, and the background fills it. 
If you want to change the way the background is painted, paint it in the overridden `paintComponent(g)`.
If you want to change the way the `JPanel` is painted within its parent, you need to override the parent's `paintComponent(g)`.
(Overriding `paintComponent(g)` means you override the layout defined by the layout manager).

Comment: I would not want to override the layout of the parent panel. I am using an AbsoluteLayout to put the panel on the image on top of another panel. I guess I can try to set a clear background and draw a rectangle inside the panel. Unless other options exist...

Comment: EDIT: No this option does not work. A part of the border gets hidden as it goes outside of the boundaries of the JPanel background.

Comment: By `AbsoluteLayout` i guess you mean null layout manager so  you are not using layout manager anyway. For more help please post [mcve], clarify what is the desired output (I guess it means a new question)